# Find common values in many tables

Tags: sql, impala

I have 5 tables and I want to find the common values between them in one column. The column name differs in two tables(account_number, account,account_id).

```
select * from db.table1 as a 
INNER JOIN db.table2 as b
ON a.account = b.account_id
INNER JOIN db.table3 as c
ON a.account = c.account_number
INNER JOIN db.table4 as d 
ON a.account  = d.account_number
INNER JOIN db.table_5 as f
ON a.account = f.account_number;`
```

I tried the above with the idea of every time compare the last result of the inner join with the new one but it seems wrong.

Comment: It would be helpful with some example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is okay, but it can return duplicates.  Another method is to use `union all`:

```
select account
from ((select account, 'a' as which from db.table1) union all
      (select account_id, 'b' as which from db.table2) union all
      (select account_number, 'c' as which from db.table3) union all
      (select account_number, 'd' as which from db.table4) union all
      (select account_number, '3' as which from db.table5) 
     ) t
group by account
having count(distinct which) = 5;
```

Note that this can be easily tweaked to get accounts that are in three or four tables rather than in all of them.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please help me to understand the having count(distinct which) = 5 ?

Comment: @Thkas . . . That is counting the number of tables the account is in.  You want accounts in all five tables.